# how to find out null values in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

im trying to find a way to alert when there is a null values in an object, if its present it should alert fail and if it doesn't it continues with the another action. Currently im able to alert  for each key. with this code:

```
var ave = {
 'a': '02',
 'b': '04',
 'c': '',
 'd': '',
 'f': '07'
 };

var total = 0
$.each(ave, function(key, value) {
  var numbersA = total + value.length;
    if (numbersA === 0) {
       alert("Fail!");
     } else {
       alert("Pass!");
     }
});
```

It pops up Fail! twice and Pass 3 times. i want it to alert fail even if there is single null value present in the object. Is there way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean if a null (by which you seem to mean any falsy) value is found, the alert should fire and the loop should exit?

Comment: Just `return false` on fail. Btw, `''` is not null, `0` is not null, `null` is null.

Comment: `null !== ''` as @elclanrs said. Are you looking for falsy values or just empty strings?

Comment: im looking for an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `for in` loop; jQuery's `jQuery.each` isn't well-suited to this situation.

```
var ave = {
 'a': '02',
 'b': '04',
 'c': '',
 'd': '',
 'f': '07'
};

var success = true;

for(var x in ave) {
    if(ave.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        if(ave[x] === '') {
            success = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(success) {
    alert('Pass!');
} else {
    alert('Fail!');
}
```

Comment: `for in` is also more well-suited as you can just `return false` in the scope it belongs to. The `success` var would be redundant here if you didn't need alerts, unlike `$.each` which would have a function closure for each key->value iteration (and I've never seen anyone iterating object properties with `$.each` successfully). +1

Comment: [I missed but the shortest one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336410/how-to-find-out-null-values-in-an-object-in-javascript/11336607#11336607).

Answer (score 1):

Just set a global variable named `failed` and alter its value if any of the properties are null:

```
var ave = {
 'a': '02',
 'b': '04',
 'c': '',
 'd': '',
 'f': '07'
 };

var failed = false;
var total = 0;
$.each(ave, function(key, value) {
  var numbersA = total + value.length;
    if (numbersA === 0) {
       failed = true;
    }
});
if (failed)
    alert("Fail!");
```

Also, note that I'm using your method to check for `null` values, which is incorrect. If you wanted to actually check for `null` values, you would changed

```
if (numbersA === 0) {
    failed = true;
}
```

to

```
if (numbersA === null) {
    failed = true;
}
```

and then, if you wanted `ave` to fail, you would need to change the empty strings to `null` as well:

```
 var ave = {
 'a': '02',
 'b': '04',
 'c': null,
 'd': null,
 'f': '07'
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the following code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/yFmW5/), play with the two sets of data. Note, that the default is 'ave_success', so the alert "Success !" will pop up when you will open the link.

Change "$.each(ave_success" to  "$.each(ave_fail" to verify that the wrong data is rejected.

Note that an empty string '' is not considered as null

```
'' === null
```

will return false

```
var ave_fail = {
  'a': '02',
  'b': '04',
  'c': '',
  'd': '',
  'f': '07'
};

var ave_success = {
  'a': '02',
  'b': '04',
  'f': '07'
};

var total = 0
var success = true;

$.each(ave_success, function(key, value) {
  var numbersA = total + value.length;
  if (numbersA === 0) {
    alert("Fail on index " + key + ' !');
    success = false;
    return false;
  }
});

if (success) alert("Success !");
```

​

Comment: A link is not an answer. Please include your code in your answer.

Comment: 1. Links are not answers (+1 @minitech). 2. It alerts success when it shouldn't!?

Comment: Sorry guys, I won't do it again. @FabrícioMatté, please read my answer concerning 2.

Comment: @minitech sorry, answer completed

Answer (score 0):

I missed it but the shortest one

```
var ave = {
  'a': '1',
  'b': '04',
  'c': '4',
  'd': '',
  'f': '1'
};

(function(){
    var v='Success';    
    for(var x in ave) if(!ave[x]) { v='Fail'; break;}
    alert(v);    
})();
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wssGs/2/)

**OR**

```
function is_falsy(arg){
  var what=true;    
  for(var x in arg) if(!arg[x]) { what=false; break;}
  return what;    
}
alert(is_falsy(ave));
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wssGs/3/)